# TypeScript overloads and optional arguments

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have a function that has some overloads.

```
function foo(x: number, y: void): void;
function foo(x: number, y: number | string): number;
function foo(x: number, y: any) {
    if (typeof y === "undefined") {
        return;
    }
    return typeof y === "string"
        ? x / parseFloat(y)
        : x / y;
}
```

Instead of using the optional argument for `y`, I specifically use `void` to specify the return value. The intended use cases include one where it is called with `undefined` as the second argument.

In another function, I will call it like so:

```
function bar(x: number, y?: number | string) {
    const f = foo(x, y);
    // Some other stuff
}
```

This causes the following type error:

```
Argument of type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
```

My understanding was that `foo` would take as the second argument a `string | number | void`, and that when `bar` invokes it, it would be passed either `string`, `number`, or `void`, and TypeScript would be clear about the `foo`'s return value.

What is the correct way of achieving the intended effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for the compiler to know whether `y` inside `bar` will be of type `number | string` or `undefined` since both are possible. If the compiler is not able to figure this out there is no way it can pick the correct overload. You have to provide more help to the compiler:

Assert that `y` can never be `undefined`:

```
function bar(x: number, y?: number | string) {

    // Picks `function foo(x: number, y: number | string): number;` overload
    const f = foo(x, y!); // Use the non-null assertion operator here.
    // Some other stuff
}
```

Or use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards):

```
function bar(x: number, y?: number | string) {

    if (y === undefined) {
        // Picks `function foo(x: number, y: void): void;` overload
        foo(x, y);
    }
    else {
        // Picks `function foo(x: number, y: number | string): number;` overload
        const a = foo(x, y);
    }
    // Some other stuff
}
```